# Develop Mobile App like webapp.to

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile

*Well, i know the title look like general question which will be discussed.*

### **But please read it first.**

There is a site that selling mobile website `webapp.to` but if we open/download one of their work/portfolio like `webapp.to/schoolofsurf` from our iphone. Then the site will opened on safari. Then the website we open will also suggest us to `Add to Home Screen` and then icon appear on Home Screen like an normal application, which it when we open it, it is normally open safari and go to that website.

But, what the real happen is the app is look like it opened stand-alone without safari.
**How did they do that?**

Please look at screenshot below for more graphic explanation:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: +1 for interesting question - it's not well formed though :) but please scale down this images a bit, they're huge

Comment: @rokjarc i would like to scale down the image, but i'm afraid the text on image will be hard to read if do that.

Comment: ok, it was just a suggestion. it's hard to see what's going on with  this images but ctrl+'-' does the trick in mozilla :) hope you get some good answers here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several iphone/safari specific HTML meta tags that allows you to set the icon, splash screen and the visibility of the location bar when your site has been added to the home screen. You can read more about this in this [document](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html).

Comment: +1 nice documentation & get some clue, also their app also work on Blackberry and windows 7, even though how it will looks like in there.

Comment: Yup, it's an HTML5 specification. An example can be found here http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/html5-iphone-app/

Comment: It's not really HTML5 but better Apple's custom extension (the meta tags in question are even prefixed with "apple-")

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a meta tag that tells Safari your webapp is "app capable". Have a look here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html.

You can specify the home screen icons using a set of "link" tags. See here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html.